# Attempted import error: 'fade' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/styles'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Tried every possible solutions I found in internet. I upgraded all the dependencies and packages using yarn - below from package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
  "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
  "@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^5.0.0-beta.1",
  "@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.41",
  "@material-ui/pickers": "^4.0.0-alpha.12",
  "@material-ui/styles": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
  "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
  "axios": "^0.21.1",
  "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
  "moment": "^2.29.1",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-router": "^5.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
  "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
}
```

Before upgrading packages I used:

```
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
```

After then I imported these:

```
import LocalizationProvider from '@material-ui/lab/LocalizationProvider';
import AdapterDateFns from '@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
```

and tried below code:

```
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                    <Grid container justifyContent="space-around">
                        <DatePicker 
                            disableToolbar 
                            variant="inline" 
                            format="DD/MM/yyyy"  
                            margin="normal" 
                            label="Date" 
                            name="date"
                            value={values.date}
                            onChange={(date) => handleInputChange(convertToDefault(date))}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                </LocalizationProvider>
```

Can you help me out? It's quite hassle :/

Answer (score 5):

use this version works fine for me...yarn add @material-ui/core@4.11.4 @material-ui/pickers

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.11.4",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
```

Answer (score 4):

```
- import { fade } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
+ import { alpha } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const classes = makeStyles(theme => ({
-  backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.primary.main, theme.palette.action.selectedOpacity),
+  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.primary.main, theme.palette.action.selectedOpacity),
}));
```

Comment: please see -->  https://next.material-ui.com/guides/migration-v4/#styles

Answer (score 2):

Hi I don't think it's a part of @material-ui/pickers any more.
You can check this https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/issues/2157

Comment: does _next material ui_ conflict with _material ui_ ?

Comment: @RishadTanjim yes since they are from different version. 
You're able to use @material-ui/pickers if you downgrade the material ui version

Answer (score 0):

**For me its working fine with exact these version. Use the exact same versions and thanks me later. If it not allowed you installation then use --force flag.**

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use 'fade' from material-ui anymore, as this is deprecated. You can use 'alpha' instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).